# soapUI changes (disables) proxy settings of Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, proxy, soapui

- installed **soapUI 4.5.1**.
- When i start soapUI it disabled all checkoxes in IE 8 `Internet Options > Connection > LAN Settings`.
- If i enter a proxy in soapUI > `File Preferences > Proxy Settings`, then soapUI overwrites the configuration in IE with this proxy

The toggle button `Apply proxy defined in global preferences` in the iconbar has no effect on IE, only on soapUI connections.

**How can i disable this behaviour?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found out, that when you uncheck File > Preferences > UI Settings `Opens startup web page when starting soapUI` then the proxy settings in IE stay untouched.

Comment: Thank god, this is by far one of the most annoying things I've ever run into.

Comment: @AlastairPitts. I felt the same and thats why i investigated some time in finding a solution. Glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing.
Sadly I love the test suites and the "Test on Demand" Tab does the same thing.

## Solution

I've found out, it you untick:
UI Settings -> Disable Browser - Disables integrated Browser component
you can get rid of this behavior completely