# Error while enter URL in WSDL location in SoapUI

Tags: testing, soapui

I have got below error message when I have enter the URL in WSDL location

```
Error loading [http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Reference to undefined entity: nbs
```

Comment: Note: The WSDL referenced in step 2 of this tutorial has been removed. Please use one of the following WSDL URLs instead:
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL
http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use soap UI with web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036624/how-to-use-soap-ui-with-web-services)

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same problem.

I did try to download the wsdl and import the downloaded wsdl... it didn't solve. I also try to found the "entity nbsp" on the file with no results.

This problem is not related with your wsdl but it's a soapUI problem. I had this problem with 5.0.0 version and i installed the 4.5.1 version and it worked =)

Just a note: look out with the proxy setting problem. This version is affected by this problem.. the solution is easy and it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433913/soapui-changes-disables-proxy-settings-of-internet-explorer/11506084#11506084)

Answer (score -1):

So, if you are trying to access a WSDL the first thing i would recommend is try to open it in a web browser(any will do...yes even IE). Do this from the same machine from where you are going to run the test.

This will tell you if you have access to the WSDL from your test machine and if the WSDL is valid.

Once the WSDL opens, copy the URL into the soapUI's new project dialog box. This will create nodes for all service operations in the service and if you have the option selected, it will also create a sample request for each service option.

This is what a wsdl open in a browser(chrome in this case looks like)[image: WSDL opened in browser]

This is what the soapUI new project dialog box looks like. Do remember to check "Create sample requests for all operations?" option to create sample requests. You can give it any name..i called it stackoverflow[image: soapUI new project dialog]

This is what a wsdl loaded into soapUI looks like, notice the different sub nodes?[image: project in soapUI]

If you are looking for WSDL to play with..check out the ones listed on [xmethods](http://www.xmethods.net/ve2/index.po) or [webservcex](http://www.webservicex.net/).

Hope this answers both this questions and [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036624/how-to-use-soap-ui-with-web-services)

Comment: The question does not ask about this at all. It implies the OP already knows how to add WSDLs, but he's getting a specific exception for that WSDL.