# SoapUI Error: Reference to undefined entity: nbsp while importing WSDL in New SOAP UI project

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I am trying to connect and send a request to a service via Soap UI. I connected via putty.In the browser, i am able to get wsdl but while importing the WSDL in New SOAP UI project ,i am getting error:Reference to undefined entity: nbsp.
Complete trace below:

```
Error loading [http://localhost:9874/ode/processes/services/services/AddCustomerBillingAccountResponseService_V0_2?xsd=AddCustomerBillingAccount.0.2]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Reference to undefined entity: nbsp
```

I saw the link: [Error while enter URL in WSDL location in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037449/error-while-enter-url-in-wsdl-location-in-soapui). But could not find a suitable solution for this. In the link, one answer is given as "**This problem is not related with your wsdl but it's a soapUI problem. I had this problem with 5.0.0 version and i installed the 4.5.1 version and it worked =)**". However i am working on SOAP UI version 4.5.1 itself. 
Help appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any other versions of SoapUI? Can you post a link to the WSDL?

Comment: Can you check your wsdl for the presence of `&nbsp;` text? if it is present is should be replaced with `&#160;` as `&nbsp;` is only defined in html and not recognized in xml. See http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200211/post20600.html for reference.

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana ...yup....nothing like &nbsp; string is present.

Comment: @SiKing...yeah...tried with version 5.0.0-beta and version 4.5.1 both.Sorry cannot post the wsdl url due to privacy policies :( .

Comment: When you search for that string, don't do it when you have it open in a browser. Look for the text in the source of the wsdl in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I added this to web.config, and now it's solved

`<location path="ABC">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>`

Comment: i was experiencing a similar issue. Having a look 'autorization' within web.config resolved issue.

Comment: Where is this web.config ? Is it a soap UI config file ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've solved this by now; however, I got the same error today. My problem wasn't a blank space in the WSDL as many seem to think.

My issue was authentication.

Using Windows Auth, the web.config was only allowing a handful of network users. When I allowed *, I cleared the error and SoapUI properly created the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and desactivate the proxy (file/preferences/proxy setting) solved error.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, go to your application ==> Authorization.
Rightclick the enabled form of authentication and select edit. 
If the authorization there is set to 'IUser', that will most likely be your problem. Change it to 'Application pool security'.