# ERROR loading WSDL into SOAPUI when testing the web service created by Anypoint(mule)

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui, anypoint-studio

I am completely new to AnyPoint Platform, and wanted to give it a shoot by running the "howto-wrapping a SOAP web service over a data base" I strictly followed the instructions and successfully got the APP deployed in AnyPoint. 
However,when I wanted to test the web service by SOAPUI,  an error came out 
[error loading wsdl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9dPU.jpg)
 I tried to open it in the browser and it worked. Could anyone give any hint about how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

This is how the WSDL opened in the IE look like:
[wsdl opend in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn6cL.jpg)

Comment: I also refered to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037449/error-while-enter-url-in-wsdl-location-in-soapui.But could not find a SOAPUI release 4.5.1　on web

Comment: Could you convert the graphics back into text. Graphics are hard to search!

Comment: @wucellin, so which version are you using? By the way, you can check with wsdl service provider to see what is causing the problem.